# ODS Excel vs ODS Tagsets.excelxp options SAS

Tags: excel, sas, ods

I am trying to use the new ODS EXCEL instead of ODS Tagsets.Excelxp since I need .XLSX file. Everything works fine but I am getting trouble with the font:
The code I used is:

```
ods Excel file="c/Profitability_ttm.xlsx" 
style= sasdocprinter
options(Sheet_Name="<1% >12%" 
Orientation= "landscape"
    embedded_titles='on');
title1 font=Arial h=10pt j=left Bold "Commercial Real Estate LOB";
```

I get the font size =10, left justified and Bold but the Font I get is Helvetica. The same code produces the Arial font when I use the ODS Tagsets.excelxp.

Is there anything I am missing in my code?

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: What version of SAS do you have? If SAS 9.4TS1M2 or lower then it's still experimental.

Comment: I am writing a code on SAS E.G. 7.1

Comment: SAS Version, not EG version. Use the following code to determine your SAS version if you don't know how: `%put &sysvlong;`

Comment: You only have code to set the font of the title. Does the title appear in Arial?

Comment: @Reeza: it gives me 9.04.01M3P062415

Comment: @Tom: That was my question. I got everything as needed except the font. Instead of Arial I got Helvetica.

Comment: See updated answer. You need to use a font that SAS knows about.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to have the font installed on the machine where SAS runs. When I run using `FONT=ARIAL` on Windows it works. When I run it on SAS UE (so on a Linux virtural machine) it used Helvetica to replace Arial. But I can ask for other fonts like 'ITC Bookman' and it works.  Try using 'Arial Unicode MS' instead of 'Arial' for the font.

Try using `PROC QDEVICE` to see what fonts are available.

Also SAS would not generate a working XLSX file on Windows until I used a value for the SHEET_NAME that did not include `<>`.

```
ods excel
  file="c:\downloads\font_test.xlsx" 
  style= sasdocprinter
  options (
    Sheet_Name="lt 1% gt 12%" 
    Orientation= "landscape"
    embedded_titles='on'
  )
;
title1 font='Arial Unicode MS' h=10pt j=left Bold "Commercial Real Estate LOB";
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods excel close ;
```

Comment: I am not sure. The same code creates the .XLSX file for me even with that sheet_name.